# First Child Qualified Heading

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the format of a set of tabs - The first  being aligned to the left and the last to the right, with those in between in the center, a shortened version: https://jsfiddle.net/qqwc51sb/2/.

```
.krown-tabs .titles li {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 20%;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}
.krown-tabs .titles h5 {
  text-align: center;
}
.krown-tabs .titles h5:first-child {
  text-align: left;
}
```

The `:first-child` doesn't work, I think because `<h5>` is qualified. However, the rest of the formatting for the tab text is within this selector, and doesn't work without the `<h5>`.

Thank you

Comment: Remember, all `:first-child` does is ask **one** question: *Am I the first child element of my parent element?*

Answer (score 4):

You should use `:first-child` and `:last-child` for `<li>`, Not `<h5>`. Like this:

```
.krown-tabs li:first-child h5 {
  background: red;
}
.krown-tabs li:last-child h5 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```css
.krown-tabs .titles li, .memberdeck .dashboardmenu li {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 20%;
    display: table;
    float: left;
 }
.krown-tabs .titles h5 {
    text-align: center;
}
.krown-tabs .titles h5:first-child {
    text-align: left;
}
.krown-tabs li:first-child h5 {
  background: red;
}
.krown-tabs li:last-child h5 {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="krown-tabs clearfix">
  <ul class="titles clearfix autop">
    <li class="">
      <h5>All</h5>
    </li>
    <li class="opened">
    <h5>Arts</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5>Fashion</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5>Food & Drink</h5>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h5>Wellbeing</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```